# How to "automatically" remove unused units from uses clause?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Does anyone know about a utility, that can automatically detect and remove unrequired units from the `uses` clause?

Preferably it ..

- can be run against a unit and/or a project
- is free and works with Delphi 2010

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmmm. How about searching for "[delphi] unused uses" on this site? :-)

Comment: I suppose you're right... please forgive me, this is my very first question posted on SO. 

However, the notion of posting a very specific question and getting a prompt, up-to-date response, from people willing to share is very compelling :)

LONG LIVE DELPHI!!!  (sorry I couldn't resist)

Comment: No prob. I just wanted to give you a heads up. :-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try using the "Uses Unit Cleaner" Wizard from [CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en) you can download from [here](http://www.cnpack.org/showdetail.php?id=669&lang=en)

[image]

Another option is use [ICARUS](http://www.peganza.com/download.htm).

> ICARUS is a small subset of Pascal
>   Analyzer. It parses Delphi or Borland
>   Pascal source code and generates a
>   list of unneeded unit references in
>   your uses lists

Comment: Thanks, these both look very promising.

Sidebar: It never ceases to amaze me how I've managed to miss little nuggets, like these... after using Delphi for more than a decade!

Comment: The uses cleaner in cnPack is awesome, although I've found it a bit buggy when removing unused units (works great in finding them).  Sometimes it removes some extra characters.

Comment: It's also worth checking out Pascal Analyser also from Peganza, which adds a lot of functionality beyond Icarus

Comment: ICARUS is no longer listed as a product at Peganza.

Comment: _"Pascal Analyzer Lite replaces ICARUS, our free product for analysis of Delphi uses lists."_

Answer (score 9):

ICARUS from [Peganza](http://www.peganza.com/) does something similar.

Comment: Since 2017 Icarus is replaced with [Pascal Analyzer lite](https://www.peganza.com/products_pal.html)