# Delphi: Which are the downsides of having unused units listed in the uses clause?

Tags: delphi, uses-clause

I use [cnPack Uses cleaner](http://www.cnpack.org/showdetail.php?id=447&lang=en), but in general which are the downsides of having useless units?

I know some of them:

1) of course if the unit is never used across the full project there will be useless resource consuption

2) the code insight will give useless results

3) the code insight will be slower

But imagine a simple case:

- I have a project with 2 forms, I use StrUtils in one of them but I declared StrUtils in both of them... Is there any downside in temrs of memory consumption in this case or not?

Comment: codeinsight is really funny feature, so yes, its better to not disturb it unless necessary. otherwise effects are negligible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. In general smartlinking works like this:

- If you use an unit somewhere, at least the **inialization and finalization** code is linked in.
- In principle, only the functions/methods that you actually use, directly or indirectly from the **main program** (.dpr) are linked in.
- Some bits that are reachable via **RTTI** will also be linked in. Rule of thumb is that RTTI for enums is always linked in (if you use the enum), and that (as soon as you construct a class), everything **published**, or reachable via published properties is linked in.
- Keep in mind that the initialization of unused units might pull in **dlls** or even whole frameworks of dlls (like .NET) that might be an unnecessary complication ofdeployment.
- (As Rob says in the comments) **Resources** are another factor that are always linked in, since due to their runtime usage the compiler can't determine if they are used or not.
- in DLLs or package projects, all published symbols will be linked in, since an external program might call them.

Conclusion: the final .exe size is determined

- mostly by **anything reachable** by above roots (mainprogram, initialization,finalization,RTTI of classes that *can* be constructed),
- some bits that are always linked in if the unit is USED (resources, certain forms of RTTI like enums),
- **language helpers** in the RTL, like ansistring helper routines, most of these are in System, some might be in variants.
- Some relative small **internal program administration** (e.g. tables with units that determine initialization/finalization order), tables needed for resource handling, DLL linking etc.
- **Debug info** (if TD32 on)
- **compiler settings** like optimization and runtime checks also mildly influence binary size.
- Binary compression utils like UPX. I **don't recommend** these though, since in my experience they constantly cause problems.

Free Pascal roughly works in the same way, the defaults are just different; Debug is currently nearly always "in binary" (like TD32), and in snapshots, smartlinking is off by default. (in official releases it is on though).

Moreover one must not lose sight of the magnitude. Strutils in its entirety is like 15kb max.

**(update 2011-11-01)**

Got a remark from sb on this reply I liked to share:

Basically he shed doubt on the remark that enums are always linked in. Maybe the registering of a class that has a published property of the enum type drags them in. The reasoning makes sense, but I haven't tested it yet.  So RTTI of enum directly can be only linked if typeinfo(tenumtype) is queried somewhere, or if it is used in a published section of the class which is used. (directly or typeinfo(theclass) is queried)

Comment: Memory issues aside, the compiler has to resolve those dependencies before it can cull them. But the real issue is clutter distracting you from seeing what a unit is really using.

Comment: I didn't speak out about source readability and compile speed to not confuse the discussion. In the case of strutils a forgotten initialization is not bad, but certain units could pull in DLLs in the initialization, which you must then deploy and manage (in the installer).

Comment: Also, in the exemple given in the question, I believe there would be essentially no difference in memory size (Less than 50 bytes I guess?) since the unit is already used by another unit in the project.

Comment: In that case, zero. (unless 2010+ RTTI changes that)

Comment: **Resource files** also get included simply by using a unit, even if you use no code from the unit. (That's the entire purpose of the TXPManifest component, to bring in the XPMan unit, which links in the default manifest resource. The component itself does nothing, but putting it on a form makes the IDE add the unit to your project.)

Answer (score 7):

Delphi smart linker will ignore unused code so normally the presence of these "extra" units does not increase the size of the compiled program.

Here are some points i get from [this link](http://delphi.about.com/od/devutilities/ss/icarus-delphi-unit-uses-clause-analyzer.htm) about downsides of unused units

1. Cleaner code to maintain, no need to bother about code that is not used
2. Code from initialization and finalization sections in unused units is not linked in
3. Compilation runs smoother and quicker

Comment: +1 for maintainability.  Especially useful when troubleshooting bugs that happen during initialization.  Time spend looking at unused units is time wasted.

Answer (score 6):

The biggest problem, to my mind, is that you can sometimes get caught out by Delphi scoping rules.  If you have two identifiers with the same name in different units, then using this name refers to the one declared in the unit declared latest in the uses clause.

If you suffer from a problem due to this you can always fully specify the identifier. What I would really love to see would be compiler warnings to tell you if you are naming an identifier that whose identity is only determined by this *latest declaration in uses clause* scoping rule.